# SSRS report with 2 details and excluding rows that exist in detail 1

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm writting a SSRS Report using sql server and I have the following problem
I need 2 details in my report
Detail 1 - is generated by a Stored Procedure that get the set of data from differents tables.

Detail 2 - I had a different stored procedure to get my datase for this detail but I need to show only those rows there are not in a Detail 1. 
I tried to use filter referencing a different dataset but this doesn't work...
Can someone an idea of how can I do that?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

@Eliana: Here i am little confused with Detail 1 and Detail 2:

If you have any operation that can be done in SQL try resolving in SQL stored procedures only as the query processing is fast. After that you can use the SSRS report to just display the records based on some parameter.
It's my personal experince for improving performance of the report.

Please share some sample input/output you want to display.